# SQL server Stuff on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to concatenate the value of multiple columns for the same ID.
I managed to concatenate for the first column, but when trying the same syntax for the second I'm having an error "The multi-part identifier EnqAct.[ActionID] could not be bound."

[Example_Data_Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzu5k.gif)

Here I managed to group several MachineName together, as seen in "Column1" but I can't manage to group both the MachineName and Description in their own column

My working Query :

```
SELECT Enq.[EnquiryID],
       Enq.[CustomerName],
       DetPrio.[Description],
       Stuff((SELECT ', ' + Mach.[MachineName]
              FROM   [dbo].[Machine] Mach
                     INNER JOIN [dbo].[MachineEnquiry] MachEnq
                             ON Mach.[MachineID] = MachEnq.[MachineID]
              WHERE  Enq.[EnquiryID] = MachEnq.[EnquiryID]
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),
       DetAct.[Description]
FROM   [dbo].[Enquiry] Enq
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[EnquiryAction] EnqAct
               ON EnqAct.[EnquiryID] = Enq.[EnquiryID]
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[DetailsAction] DetAct
               ON DetAct.[ActionID] = EnqAct.[ActionID]
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[DetailsPriority] DetPrio
               ON DetPrio.[PriorityID] = Enq.[Priority]
GROUP  BY Enq.[EnquiryID],
          Enq.[CustomerName],
          DetPrio.[Description],
          DetAct.[Description]
```

My non working Query :

```
SELECT Enq.[EnquiryID],
       Enq.[CustomerName],
       DetPrio.[Description],
       Stuff((SELECT ', ' + Mach.[MachineName]
              FROM   [dbo].[Machine] Mach
                     INNER JOIN [dbo].[MachineEnquiry] MachEnq
                             ON Mach.[MachineID] = MachEnq.[MachineID]
              WHERE  Enq.[EnquiryID] = MachEnq.[EnquiryID]
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),
       Stuff((SELECT ', ' + DetAct.[Description]
              FROM   [dbo].[DetailsAction] DetAct
                     INNER JOIN [dbo].[EnquiryAction] EnqAct
                             ON EnqAct.[ActionID] = DetAtc.[ActionID]
              WHERE  Enq.[EnquiryID] = EnqAct.[EnquiryID]
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM   [dbo].[Enquiry] Enq
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[DetailsPriority] DetPrio
               ON DetPrio.[PriorityID] = Enq.[Priority]
GROUP  BY Enq.[EnquiryID],
          Enq.[CustomerName],
          DetPrio.[Description]
```

Both work the same way, I have a table Enquiry which will have an EnquiryID.
then in my table EnquiryAction or MachineEnquiry I will have entitys with an EnquiryID and an Action/Machine ID
Then in my DetailsAction/Machine Table I will have the Action/Machine ID, and the string I want to get and concatenate.

Why am I having an error and is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: Just checking; does this portion of the query work when run by itself?  SELECT ', ' + DetAct.[Description]
                                                FROM [dbo].[DetailsAction] DetAct
                                                INNER JOIN [dbo].[EnquiryAction] EnqAct
                                                ON EnqAct.[ActionID]  = DetAtc.[ActionID]

Comment: Is this typo in your testing query? `DetAtc.[ActionID]` in your second `STUFF`

Comment: Well it did not ... but resting 5min instead of suffering on this problem for hours allowed me to see that I wrote "DetAtc" instead of "DetAct" ...

It now works as expected.